# How can we configure Artifactory to auto-assign OAuth users to LDAP groups?

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak, openid-connect, artifactory

I've got Artifactory set up to allow SSO via an OIDC client in Keycloak. Keycloak talks to Active Directory in the background. I've also got the same Active Directory configured within Artifactory. I've also configured Keycloak to provide user groups in the `userinfo` structure.

**What I'm trying to do is to get OAuth users to automatically be added to the imported LDAP groups within Artifactory.** I don't mind if this is done via the `userinfo` structure or via a separate LDAP lookup when a user logs in. However I can't seem to figure out how to achieve this.

I know that Artifactory provides a plugin called `synchronizeLdapGroups.groovy`, which seems to advertise doing what I need, however it seems like the plugin is not actually taking effect. That is to say, users do not end up with the permissions that being in the LDAP groups would provide.

I've attempted to write a plugin myself to do what I need, but when I make the API call to add the groups to the user, the plugin crashes. It's unclear why at this point.

It seems like others have used the SCIM feature in Artifactory for something akin to this (mostly via SAML rather than OIDC though), however Keycloak doesn't support SCIM out of the box and the SCIM plugin I've tried using has similarly given me no results.

**Has anyone done something similar to this, and has a working solution I could follow?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a specific group you want all users to be in you could try:

- Under Security - OAuth SSO settings tab - check "Auto Create Users"
- Under Identity and Access - Groups - select the specific group and check "Automatically Join New Users To The Group"

I'm guessing you want to automatically sync user-group association between Keycloak and Artifactory. SCIM is what you're looking for but there's a known issue specifically with Keycloak SCIM plugin.
We're looking into the SCIM plugin for Keycloak (can't commit on a specific timeline for a fix but it should be sometime this quarter).

If you only need the association in the UI you could try SAML with "Auto associate groups" set. It won't apply the groups association for APIKey/Token calls but it would work for the UI.

---

EDIT:
after further investigation github.com/Captain-P-Goldfish/scim-for-keycloak isn't relevant here - it makes keycloak a SCIM client, not a SCIM server. There's no official support of SCIM in keycloak, see issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-2537 . and there's no working plugin for keycloak that makes it a SCIM server that I could find (tried a few, all broken). For now Artifactory can't support SCIM with Keycloak

Comment: "I'm guessing you want to automatically sync user-group association between Keycloak and Artifactory." This is correct.

Comment: Would you have a link or something explaining the specific issue with SCIM/Keycloak that you referred to?

Comment: there's an internal ticket for it JA-2488 (no public ticket). We're looking into this one: https://github.com/Captain-P-Goldfish/scim-for-keycloak

Comment: What exactly is the nature of the known bug?

Comment: update - after further investigation github.com/Captain-P-Goldfish/scim-for-keycloak isn't relevant here - it makes keycloak a SCIM client, not a SCIM server. There's no official support of SCIM in keycloak, see https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-2537 . and there's no working plugin for keycloak that makes it a SCIM server that I could find (tried a few, all broken). For now Artifactory can't support SCIM with Keycloak.

Comment: Are there any tutorials or examples I can follow for configuring Keycloak SAML and Artifactory? I can only find examples for ADFS and it's very confusing.

Comment: There's no official documentation that I'm aware of. I'll suggest to create one. Anyway the gist is - in keycloak create a saml client, check 'Sign Assertions', uncheck 'Client signature required', uncheck 'force POST binding', uncheck 'front channel logout', set 'Valid redirect Uri' as <ip>/*, Under Fine Grain SAML Endpoint Configuration set <ip>/ui/login for both logout urls. In Artifactory set login & logout to <keycloakip>/auth/realms/keyCloak/protocol/saml and for SAML Certificate - take from keycloak Realms settings > Keys > Public Keys > Certificate > RS256 (Use=SIG)

Comment: FYI I'm not sure how secure it is, just got it to work

Comment: Having a bit of trouble setting up the group synchronisation. I've created a mapper in Keycloak:
Protocol: saml
ID: xxxxxx
Name: member
Mapper Type: Group list
Group attribute name: member
Friendly Name: member
SAML Attribute NameFormat: Basic
Single Group Attribute: Off
Full group path: Off

In Artifactory:
Auto Associate Groups: On
Group Attribute: member
Auto Create Artifactory Users: On
Allow Created Users Access To Profile Page: On
Auto Redirect Login Link to SAML Login: Off
Verify Audience Restriction: Off

Does this look right?

Comment: Never mind, I changed the Single Group Attribute to ON and then fixed up the group definitions in Artifactory (was a mistake there) and now my user gets admin rights as expected!